# plsql procedure is not a procedure or is undefined

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a plsql procedure to calculate the factorial of a given number.

This is the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fact(x IN number, fact OUT number)
IS
BEGIN
while x > 0 loop
fact := x*fact;
x := x-1;
END loop;
END;
/
```

`Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.`

and this is where I'm calling the function

```
DECLARE
x number := &x;
fact number  := 1;
BEGIN
fact(x,fact);
dbms_output.put_line('Factorial is: '||fact);
END;
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
Enter value for x: 5
old   2: x number := &x;
new   2: x number := 5;
fact(x,fact);
*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00221: 'FACT' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: What happens if you fix the compilation error(s)?

Comment: how to fix the error

Comment: Having parameters and variables with the same name as your procedure is going to cause problems. My suggestion: use unique names. [See this AskTom question and its responses](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532216500346723434)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your creation of procedure like this :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fact(x IN OUT number, fact OUT number) IS
BEGIN
  while x > 0 loop
    fact := x * nvl(fact, 1);
    x    := x - 1;
  END loop;
END;
/
```

and call :

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL> DECLARE
  x      number := &x;
  v_fact number := 1;
BEGIN
  fact(x, v_fact);
  dbms_output.put_line('Factorial is: ' || v_fact);
END;

Factorial is: 120
```

- You can not use a variable of type `IN` as an assignment target
- You need to initialize a null variable `fact` as `nvl(fact,1)` or `fact := 1;` just before the `while x > 0`

Actually, you even do not need an extra parameter `fact OUT number` for procedure named `fact`, and make that as local. So, your procedure may be replaced with this :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fact(x IN OUT number) IS
  fact number := 1;
BEGIN
  while x > 0 loop
    fact := x * fact;
    x    := x - 1;
  end loop;
    x := fact;
END;
/
```

Therefore, should be invoked as :

```
SQL> DECLARE
  x      number := &x;
BEGIN
  fact(x);
  dbms_output.put_line('Factorial is: ' || x);
END;

Factorial is: 120
```

Comment: I am no pl/sql expert but shouldn't the `fact` parameter be IN OUT as well so it can be given a start value?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson being an `OUT` parameter is enough for being use as an assignment target so, `fact` can also be initialized with `fact := 1;` without being converted to `IN OUT` type(already `OUT`) just before while statement.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan can you checkout this question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55777222/encountered-the-symbol-end-of-file-when-expecting-one-of-the-following

Comment: @Ajax in that question, `DECLARE` and `dbms_output.put_line(first);` should be removed. `first` outputs `0` which's not contained in the Fibonacci series, which is `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 ....`

Answer (score 1):

You might consider rewriting this as a function along the lines of the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fact(pinX IN INT)
  RETURN INT
IS
  nResult INT := 1;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 2..pinX LOOP
    nResult := i * nResult;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN nResult;
END FACT;
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=780dfc1891e8badcded6c576f026e22e)

Best of luck.