# Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to print Fibonacci series in plsql

this is the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fibos(n IN number) IS
DECLARE  
first number := 0; 
second number := 1; 
temp number;   
i number; 
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Series:'); 
dbms_output.put_line(first); 
dbms_output.put_line(second); 
for i in 2..n 
loop 
temp:=first+second; 
first := second; 
second := temp; 
dbms_output.put_line(temp); 
END loop; 
END; 
/
```

`Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.`

and this is the where I call procedure:

```
DECLARE
a number := &a;
BEGIN
fibos(a);
/
```

and this is the error I'm getting

fibos(a);
        *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the
following:
begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
 
 << close current delete fetch lock insert
open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge
pipe

Comment: The Oracle documentation is comprehensive, online and free. It has plenty of examples of valid PL/SQL syntax. For instance, [here is the section on CREATE PROCEDURE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373). I suggest you bookmark it, as it will be quicker for you to solve your own syntax bloomers than posting all your code here and asking us to debug it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `DECLARE` in the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement and add a `END;` to your anonymous block calling it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fibos(n IN number) IS
first number := 0; 
second number := 1; 
temp number;   
i number; 
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Series:'); 
dbms_output.put_line(first); 
dbms_output.put_line(second); 
for i in 2..n 
loop 
temp:=first+second; 
first := second; 
second := temp; 
dbms_output.put_line(temp); 
END loop; 
END; 
/
```

```
DECLARE
a number := &a;
BEGIN
fibos(a);
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bbe676d698a647fc800d3e913cb4f268)