# How to fix "Warning: Function created with compilation errors"?

Tags: oracle, plsql

There are two tables

> Customer2(**CUSTID**,NAME,ADDRESS,AGE,SALARY)
>
> Order2(**ORDERID**, ORDERNAME,PRICE,**CUSTID**)

the main issue is to find total no of order made by the customer from the location

this is the plsql function of I wrote:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalCustomer (loc IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
total number(2) := 0;
add CHAR := loc;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order2 WHERE cusid IN (SELECT cusid FROM customer2 WHERE address='add');
RETURN total;
END;
  /
```

and this is where I'm calling the function:

```
DECLARE
p VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
p:= &p;
dbms_output.put_line (totalCustomer (p));
END;
/
```

I'm getting this error `Warning: Function created with compilation errors.`

and this one while I'm calling the function

```
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 23:
PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.TOTALCUSTOMER is invalid
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Not related to your error, but: **NEVER**, ever create your own tables, functions, procedures or other things using the SYSTEM account. Do NOT do that. Create a regular user and create your own objects there. The SYSTEM and SYS accounts are **NOT** for normal work

Comment: Don't you use any tool that shows you the errors when compiling the function? You can also get them later with `select * from user_errors`.

Comment: Please take to heart [my comment on one of your other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55777222/encountered-the-symbol-end-of-file-when-expecting-one-of-the-following#comment98227719_55777222) regarding the value of the Oracle documentation. You should to learn how to fix syntax errors and spot typos for yourself.

Comment: The way to fix *"Warning: Function created with compilation errors"* is to review the errors and correct them. This is surely the same in any computer language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function:

- You wrote `cusid` in your query but the columns are named `custid` in the tables.
- You don't put the query result in the variable `total`. Your function will always return `0` the initial value you set for `total`.
- By writing `'add'` you compared the address to the literal string "add" rather than the contents of the variable `add`.
- But there's no need to copy `loc` to `add`. You can use `loc` directly.
- The type of `number(2)` for `total` seems a little small. Better go with `number(38)` (`integer`) instead.
- The query is better written with an inner join. `IN` with a subquery often does not perform well.
- Instead of being `char` the type of `loc` should be the type of `address` in `customer2`. You can use `customer2.address%TYPE` here.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalcustomer (loc IN customer2.address%TYPE)
                           RETURN number
IS
total number(38) := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO total
         FROM order2 o
              INNER JOIN customer2 c
                         ON c.custid = o.custid
         WHERE address = loc;
  RETURN total;
END;
/
```

And in your anonymous block:

- You declared `p` as `char` which means `char(1)`, i.e. `p` can only hold one character. I'm not sure this is what you want. You can go with `customer2.address%TYPE` here too.

```
DECLARE
  p customer2.address%TYPE;
BEGIN
  p := &p;
  dbms_output.put_line(totalcustomer(p));
END;
/
```

Comment: Good points. Anyway, I prefer the original `IN` clause approach over the join for readability.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: "Plus `address='add')`" -- Yeah I had this on my list in my mind too but forgot to write it. Thanks for the reminder!